# Error from chokidar : Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch

Tags: node.js, angular, chokidar

In a new Angular app I'm getting the following error:

`Error from chokidar : Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch`

I've deleted and re-installed `node_modules`, downloaded the entire project again etc.

Node version is `12.18.2`

Comment: `chokidar` is this any kind of package you are using?

Comment: `chokidar` is used by default when creating a new Angular app. It is used to serve the project for testing etc. https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar

Comment: i didn't know that, thanks. Can you try running `npm cache clean -f` and then same steps to install application

Comment: Yes cleared the cache and removed/reinstalled all the node_modules to try to fix it but still getting the same...

Comment: **FUN FACT**: chokidar means watchman in Hindi

Answer (score 13):

Is your project on a network drive? Move the project to local drive, issues should go away.

The files might be local, but accessed through SMB protocol (exp. through drives created with `net use Z: \\localhost\C$\path\to\my\project` command). This will generate same issue.

Comment: Thank, exactly my case.  Once, accessed from a local drive works with no probs. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue. Try creating the angular app in C drive only. Worked for me.

Comment: this helped me - most of the organizations hae network drives and they treat it like D drive or H drive , as soon as i cloned my code in C: - it started working - no other change were needed

Answer (score 4):

you need to just Delete the node module folder

```
npm install
npm cache clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Angular app in "C:" Drive only, not in any network drive. Run the app/commands from "C:" drive only and it worked for me. Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it manually.

```
npm i chokidar
```

It worked for me. I ran my project after 2 years.